# Camel rest component - post a message with clientId ans clientSecret

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, spring-camel

I'am using camel rest component in order to call an API through a post verb and i need to use a clientId & clientSecret credentials to perform the call as describe in my route example below:

```
@Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        super.configure();

        restConfiguration()
                .host(configProp.getBasePath())
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json);

        from(direct("route-api"))
                .routeId("route-api")
                .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, Message.class)
                .bean(BusinessLogic.class)
                .toD("rest:post/v1/test?arg1=${headers.agr1}");
    }
```

My questions

- Is rest component supports those kind of parameters in a good way, if yes can we provide an example ?
- What is the best approach between using camel rest component and define a separate service to do the work and then call this service in my route through a .bean() ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you elaborate more on *Is rest component supports those kind of parameters in a good way*? What are you referring to with *parameters* and what *good way* means?

Comment: Hi @tmrwen, i want to send information to another external service through a rest API call(post), those information will be sent in the path variable and query param and i could not find a way to do that using camel rest component. Since the api is secured i have to call it also with clientSecret & clientId.
That's way i was asking to konw how to add all those parameters. Thanks.